# js добавить input

Tags: javascript, input

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь. Нужен скрипт, который по нажатию кнопки будет добавлять input и устанавливать ему `name = "input_form" + N`
где `N` это количество уже имеющихся `input`.

С созданием проблем нет, нужна помощь с установкой имени. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.inputs').append('<input name="input_form'+$('.inputs input').length+'">')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="inputs">
</div>
<button>Создать</button>
```

Вариант 2:

```js
$(function() {
  var n = $('.inputs input').length
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.inputs').append('<input name="input_form'+n+'">');
    n++
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="inputs"></div>
<button>Создать</button>
```